# Displaying list containing XMLListCollection

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, mxml

I'm a Flex noob and I've been struggling with this problem for a last week, and I'm at my wits end.

I have opened the following XML file

```
<root>
<person>
<city-of-death>asdf</city-of-death>
<place-of-death>qwert</place-of-death>
</person>
<person>
<city-of-death>hjkl</city-of-death>
<place-of-death>yuio</place-of-death>
</person>
</root>
```

Using the following code

```
[Bindable]
            private var people:XMLListCollection;
private function resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void {
                people = new XMLListCollection(event.result.person);
            }
```

and am trying to display it using for following mxml

```
<s:List left="0" height="94" dataProvider="{people}" labelField="@city-of-death" width="144" y="-1"></s:List>
```

Essentially, I'm hoping to have a list displaying ... but there is nothing displayed

```
asdf
hjkl
```

I would be so incredibly grateful if someone could help. I am pulling out my hair!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@` sign is for attributes. Try to use something like:

```
<s:List left="0" height="94" dataProvider="{people}" labelField="city-of-death" width="144" y="-1"></s:List>
```

Comment: Hmmm unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. The resultFormat of the <s:HTTPService = "e4x" ... not sure if this changes anything.

Comment: If the real value of `event.result` is XML you listed `List` labels should be displayed without problems. Please place breakpoint into assign statement of your `resultHandler` and examine the real value of `event.result` in your Flash Builder Debugger's variables view.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I'm not sure what I did, but removing the @ seemed to help!